# What am I missing here: $U(144) \neq U(140)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm confused about the following exercise:

Prove that $U(144)$ is isomorphic to $U(140)$.

Here are my thoughts:

$$U(144) = U(12^2) = U(3^2)\oplus U(2^4) = \mathbb Z_{6} \oplus \mathbb Z_{8}$$

and

$$ U(140) = U(2^2 *7*5) = U(2^2) \oplus U(5) \oplus U(7) = \mathbb Z_{2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{4} \oplus \mathbb Z_{6}$$

And I have the following result:

$\mathbb Z_{n_1 \dots n_k}\cong \mathbb Z_{n_1}\oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb Z_{n_k}$ if and only if $n_i$ are pairwise coprime.

But $2$ and $4$ are not coprime therefore $\mathbb Z_{2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{4} \oplus \mathbb Z_{6}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{6} \oplus \mathbb Z_{8}$.

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $U(p^n)$ is not, in general, cyclic when $p=2$. Check $U(8)$ by hand, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $U(2^4)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$.